# Is there any tool like ITester for Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser-testing

Is there any browser test tool like ITester for mozilla all version?

Comment: Maybe if you told us what ITester is....

Comment: @skaffman may be it is IeTester

Comment: @skaffman, With a friendly tone: http://bit.ly/zHxOns

Comment: See Utilu Mozilla Firefox Collection (site: http://utilu.com/UtiluMFC/). It contains all Firefox versions, including pre-installed dev tools. Another option is to use [Firefox' Profile manager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Profile_Manager).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:
[MultiFirefox](http://davemartorana.com/multifirefox/)

I use it all the time.  I also use IE Tester.  Its not the most stable application, but it does the job.  So does MultiFirefox.  You'll like the experience.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of anything similar to IETester for Firefox. So, either:

- Use multiple installs of Firefox 2 & 3 (maybe use virtual machines to not mess with profiles)
- Use http://browsershots.org/

Comment: Firefox has portable versions, designed to run on USB sticks, that are likely to leave installed profiles alone. There was a big project for USB Stick powered software, I can't remember the name....

Comment: @Pekka Good idea (are you thinking to http://portableapps.com/).

Comment: ... PortableApps: http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable

Comment: That's the perfect solution, IMO. Multiple installs of Firefox in VMs for usability testing, and browsershots.org for quick and dirty page viewing (good for quick CSS and HTML checks). Also, if you want to extend this functionality to cross-browser testing of modern rendering engines, try out the Lunascape browser (http://www.lunascape.tv/Default.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Hai Pankaj,

Here is a list of http://freelancefolder.com/7-fresh-and-simple-ways-to-test-cross-browser-compatibility/..